# Cannot send special characters via jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, tags

I am developing a webpage where user is searching for files using tags.
I am using jQuery Ajax to do the remote call to the API (database).
It all works fine when I use non special characters like a-z but fails when using for example åäö.

On the serverside I am using PHP. I print the tag to see if it "arrives" and all a-z works fine but the åäö is not displaying at all. They seem to not "arrive".

What can be wrong?

This is my jQuery code:

```
var tags = $('#tags').val();

$.ajax ({
    type: "POST",
    url: base_url + "search", 
    data: "tags=" + tags + "&limit=" + limit, 
    beforeSend: function (html) {
            $("#search_results").html("Searching for files...");
    },
    success: function (html) {
            $("#search_results").html(html);
    },
    error: function (html) {
            $("#search_results").html('Something went wrong!');
    }
});
```

This is my server side code:

```
echo ($_POST['tags']);
```

I search and looked at related questions about this here on SO but non helped me unfortunately.

**UPDATE**

Using this solved it! Works fine now.

```
{tags: encodeURIComponent(tags), limit: limit}
```

Comment: Try `"tags=" + encodeURIComponent(tags) + "&limit=" + encodeURIComponent(limit)`, or `{tags: tags, limit: limit}`.

Comment: This don´t work either: data: "tags=" + encodeURIComponent(tags) + "&limit=" + limit

Comment: {tags: tags, limit: limit} does not work either.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Data (tags) must be encoded before sending it to server using encodeURIComponent()

Comment: This don´t work either: data: "tags=" + encodeURIComponent(tags) + "&limit=" + limit

Comment: Make sure that all parts of your flow are in UTF-8
check:
HTML page;
request encoding;
server side encoding;

`AJAX.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");`

`meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"`

Basically you will have to trace on which step character encoding is being lost.

Comment: Thanks, it solved my issue with sending special characters in Jquery AJAX request in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

Below code is working fine for sending & and "" or any special characters via ajax call:

```
specialChar1= "JΛ̊KE#2@#*&($^@%#*@#%))*$&@*(""" ;
specialchar2 ="??&!!--##";
url = "/get/" + encodeURIComponent( specialChar1) +"/"+  encodeURIComponent ( specialchar2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using JSON object.

For example:

```
[{"AttributeId":"4035","Value":"Street & House"}]
```

or, you can use `URLencode` before post.